# Java Play: bindFromRequest() not working

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework, forms, http-post

I'm experimenting with Java Play and I've hit an immediate roadblock. The situation is quite straightforward and the setup, simple.

I have a model class called `Person` that is very simple and looks like this;

```
package models.models;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * Created by asheshambasta on 25/07/14.
 */
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    public String name;
}
```

And I have a route defined as;

```
POST    /person                     controllers.Application.addPerson()
```

Next, I have an action `addPerson` inside `controllers.Application`, which is

```
public static Result addPerson() {
    Person person = form(Person.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    person.save();
    Logger.debug(person.toString());
    Logger.debug(form().get("name"));
    return redirect(controllers.routes.Application.index());
}
```

And the index.scala.html looks like:

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {
        <form action="@routes.Application.addPerson()" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" />
            <button>Add person</button>
        </form>
}
```

I've also checked my browser debug tools and I see the `name` form element correctly being posted to the server.

What happens is weird: none of the form parameters seem to be visible in the action. As you can see, I have two `Logger.debug`'s, each of which show me a null for the `name` property in the `person` object, as well as when attempted to be retrieved using `form.get("name")`.

I've tried what I could see is the best way to go about this problem but I've not really seen much about this issue online. And this seems too basic to be an issue with the Play framework.

What am I doing wrong here?

As a note, I'm on a Mac, and I'm using mySQL to store data.

Comment: Can anyone answer this? I believe this is a very simple situation and there is obviously something going awfully wrong around here. If simple cases like these cannot work, for no obvious reason/warning, I doubt relying on Play for any real world scenarios.

Comment: did you get this to work? how?

Comment: @Gevorg I'm afraid at this point I quit trying to use Java with the Play framework. I took this as a chance to dive into Scala and found much more documentation and online discussion going on about the common roadblocks. Since then I've deployed my first Play-Scala based API. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While trying play with Java, I was stuck with the same problem too.

**Cause :** The problem seems to arise when you have Eclipse project preference set to `Build automatically`. This messes up the classes generated by play and overrides it with the classes generated by eclipse upon a change.

**The solution :** `Disable the 'build automatically'` from Project settings and from the terminal, do a `play clean` to create classes from Play!

Let me know if this works, a lot of people face the same problem. This should probably be a hint in the documentation itself [Reference](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/JYlkz_Nh31g/discussion).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to create a setter/getter for the attributes? Maybe is a problem with some code generation :(. Try to change attributes to private and create the accessors methods

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to override `toString()` method in your model (also add the finder and move it directly to `models` package!):

```
package models;

import play.db.ebean.Model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    public static Finder<Integer, Person> find = new Finder<>(Integer.class, Person.class);

    public String name;

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

second, you need to `bindFromRequest()` the `form()` before accessing it's fields:

```
public static Result addPerson() {
    Person person = form(Person.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    person.save();
    Logger.debug(person.toString());
    Logger.debug(form().bindFromRequest().get("name"));
    return redirect(controllers.routes.Application.index());
}
```

finally, you can display list of existing persons i.e. under the form:

```
public static Result index() {
    List<Person> persons = Person.find.all();
    return ok(index.render(persons));
}
```

view:

```
@(persons: List[Person])

@main("Welcome to Play") {
    <form action="@routes.Application.addPerson()" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <button>Add person</button>
    </form>
}

Already added:
@for(person <- persons){
    <div>@person</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem since 2 days and found that this problem is very specific to Eclipse. I just disabled "Build Automatically" and did a "Build Clean" (unchecked Build after Clean checkbox during build clean) and found the entries to be storing in database.

I really want the intro video to include this as a safe point for eclipse users on Play framework.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add that I had recently a similar problem with JSON requests, using playframework 2.3.7. In my case, it was fixed by simply upgrading playframework to version 2.3.8 (after losing 2 full of endless debugging)

If you want to reproduce the error, you can try to download and run [Play-Authenticate's sample app](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage) and using playframework 2.3.7. In the doLogin() request, you will see that bindFromRequest fails for JSON requests.

Answer (score 0):

The first Logger call prints default implementation of *toString()* which is

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

because you haven't override it in the class Person.

Try simple

```
person.name
```

instead of

```
form().get("name")
```

to get access to the value of property.

Everything should be fine. Otherwise you would get *NullPointerException* on the *person.save()* call.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by Adding Setters and Getters.
If you have Entity/Model class you should add setters and getters.
If you have FormData classes add setters and getters for it as well.

So when you call

```
Form<YourFormData> formData = Form.form(YourFormData.class).bindFromRequest(); 
YourFormData formData = formData.get();
```

Your formData will now have all the values set.
Hope this helps!